# ¿Cómo deshabilitar botones indicando una fecha?

Tags: php, javascript

Quisiera poder bloquear un botón 48 horas antes de una fecha indicada, digamos que tengo guardada la fecha del 29/03/2019 (siendo hoy 27/03/2019), quisiera que ese botón ya estuviera deshabilitado, estoy manejando laravel, este es el botón que le indicaría esa función

```
<button onclick=\'editar("'.$sesion->idSesion.'");\' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="bloqueo">
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: ¿La fecha del cliente o del servidor o de otro lugar (UTC)? Supongo que del servidor pero es algo importante a tener en cuenta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si es la del servidor

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de comparación entre tus dos fechas lo debes de asignar al atributo disabled de la etiqueta al momento de cargar el boton. Los tipos date pueden ser comparados con los operadores matemáticos.

```
<?php
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
$vence = date_create("29-03-2019");
$isDisable = $hoy > $vence;
echo '<button type="button" disabled='.$isDisable.'> Guardar</button>';
```

Comment: ¿Ahí como le indico que se desabilite 48hrs antes de esa fecha?

Comment: Puedes a tu fecha de vencimiento restarle dos días y contra esa comparar.